# back slash in folder path changing to forward slash on browsing path through some other tool

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I am trying to run following python code's exe file by integrating it in another tool. I am receiving desired output when running the python exe standalone but I am not able to receive desired output on running through that other tool. Can somebody please provide a workaround of same without using "replace"?

**INPUT provided through browsing the path in some other tool :**
C:\Users\Coder\Desktop\PROJECT_v2.0

**OUTPUT obtained in VBS.txt:**
C:/Users/Coder/Desktop/PROJECT_v2.0/\Input.xlsx
C:/Users/Coder/Desktop/PROJECT_v2.0/\Output

**Desired OUTPUT in VBS.txt:**
C:\Users\Coder\Desktop\PROJECT_v2.0\Input.xlsx
C:\Users\Coder\Desktop\PROJECT_v2.0\Output

Code:

```
import os
def doProcess(INPATH,OUTPATH):

    xlPath = INPATH + '\Input.xlsx'
    output = OUTPATH + '\Output'
    if not os.path.isdir(output):
        os.mkdir(output)
    #Check if VBSPath folder exists else create it.
    if not os.path.isdir('C:\VBSPath'):
        os.mkdir('C:\VBSPath')
    with open('C:\VBSPath\VBS.txt','w+') as file:
        pathinfo = [xlPath, output]
        for i in pathinfo:
            file.write(i+'\n') #Stores the path of i/p excel file & o/p folder.
    file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print('Please provide input/output path.')
        sys.exit()
    INPATH = sys.argv[1]
    OUTPATH = sys.argv[2]
    doProcess(INPATH,OUTPATH)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `/` everywhere? It should work fine on any OS.

Comment: Don't hardcode separators, use the `os.path` module instead https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Comment: In the other tool, I can only give folder path and not the whole file path.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved in the following 2 ways:
1. Using forward slash instead of backward.
2. Using double backward slashes.